# Why can't I use QueryCache to get at "cache" from queryClient.prefetchQuery

Tags: next.js, react-query

So, I am trying to access the cache that I set with: queryClient.prefetchQuery, in a SSR page.

I am using this on the SSR side that I hydrate:

```
ala:
  await queryClient.prefetchQuery(['userSesion'], () => fetchUserSession());
```

// This is wrapping my _app.js file

```
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <Hydrate state={props.dehydratedState}>
```

Then on the client side, I am trying to get at this "cache".

```
  const queryCache = new QueryCache();
  queryCache.find("userSession"); // <--- This is undefined/empty
```

Also tried: no luck

```
  queryClient.getQueryData('userSession'))
  queryClient.getQueryState('userSession'))
```

Mind you, I "SEE" the data/cache in the tools, so why can't I get at it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you create a `new Cache`, and that cache has no connection to the queryClient. If you want to get the cache, you can do this via:

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient()
const queryCache = queryClient.getQueryCache()
```

that being said, there should be rarely the need to interact with the `QueryCache` directly. The `QueryClient` exposes functions to interact with the cache, and if you have a component that needs data from the cache, it's always preferred to just call `useQuery` in that component. It will give you data from the cache instantly if there is any, and perform a background refetch if the data is considered stale.

Comment: yes, that worked. I just used: queryClient.getQueryData('session'), appreciate it.
Is this an anti-pattern? I just need to display the users "name".. and need to read from the cache to get it, from the setting of it in the SSR implementation.

Comment: It doesn't create a subscription like useQuery does, so if the name changes in the cache, your component doesn’t update. Do useQuery instead and set a staleTime to avoid background updates that you don’t want.

Comment: the thing I don't like about "useQuery" is that I have tag along the "function" with it, if there was a mechanism that a second 'method' param wasn't passed, it would hand back the cache. Because in this instance, I don't want to "refetch" IF its not there... because I have it in SSR. I just want to "get the cache".